# What can I use in place of DB.Where

Tags: go, go-fiber

In Gorm we can use `DB.Where` to check the data of the user from the database for authentication. But I have to use Go Fiber so what can I use in place of `DB.Where` to check if the user is present in the database.

```
var user models.User    
database.DB.Where("id = ?", claims.Issuer).(&user)
```

Comment: Example using [fiber with gorm](https://github.com/gofiber/recipes/tree/master/gorm).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because library documentation should cover it. Seems like not enough research was done.

Comment: What's the relation between Gorm and Fiber? Seems none to me. What is preventing you from using `db.Where` normally?

Comment: db.Where is not in use on fiber version v2 while finding the user in the database.

Comment: Yes it is used, inside the fiber v2 auth middleware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as per your question gorm is working as a database also as a framework.

you can use go fiber as a framework but if you want to use the database you cannot use the database from fiber instead you have to use a database from which you can find the collection of the data in the database.

For example, you are using MongoDB with GoFiber so it will use the method of `DB.Collection.FindOne()`

In form Db.Where is used to find the database collection

Answer (score 0):

```
Well, as per your question gorm is working as a database also as a framework.

you can use go fiber as a framework but if you want to use the database you cannot use the database from fiber instead you have to use a database from which you can find the collection of the data in the database.

For example, you are using MongoDB with GoFiber so it will use the method of DB.Collection.FindOne()

In form Db.Where is used to find the database collection
```